# Dart devtools memory view not working with stack overflow error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, devtools

I tried to use the dart devtools memory view hoping to find some clues on the memory usage on my flutter app, but it's not functioning. It displayed "Stack overflow error" on the web developer console. Anyone knows what's causing the problem?

I'm using VSCode with flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5, connecting to an ipad(A1822). The app is launched in profile mode which suppose to be able to work with the memory view, but both memory view and timeline isnt working. No idea what's causing the stack overflow in js of devtools.

a screenshot on the devtools and webdev screen attached for your reference.

[Screenshot on the devtool screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjVHZ.png)

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of your consoles and/or code, but post the code directly in the post. It would be also interesting to know your development environment

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Just thought that the problem i encounter was with the debugger at chrome and i don't know which codes to quote, thus i made a screen cap instead to show...anyway I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that was resolved and patched today into DevTools v0.1.15 ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/1610#issuecomment-583393461)). Just run `pub global activate devtools` or `flutter pub global activate devtools` to upgrade and the error be resolved.

Comment: thank you very much!
I tried update the devtools to 0.1.15 and both the timeline and memory view is backon!

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Is there something I have to do after running that?